# Error in using InputPath to select parts of input in a Step Functions workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am creating a Step Functions workflow which has various steps. I am referring to this topic in their documentation [InputPath, ResultPath and OutputPath Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-example.html). I am trying to check the identity and address of a person in my workflow as they've shown in their document. I'm passing the input for the `Verify identity` step within the state machine definition inside `Parameters`. My workflow looks like this.

*Note:* But when I run this, am getting the error -> `An error occurred while executing the state 'Verify identity' (entered at the event id #19). Invalid path '$.identity' : Property ['identity'] not found in path $`

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please explain?

Thanks..

````json
{
  "StartAt": "Step1",
  "States": {
    "Step1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      ...something...
      },
      "Next": "Step2"
    },
    "Step2": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        Do something...
      ],
      "Default": "Step3.1"
    },
    "Step3.1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      ...something...
        }
      },
      "Next": "Step3.3"
    },
    ...something...,
    "Step4": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Verify identity",
          "States": {
            "Verify identity": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
              "InputPath": "$.identity",
              "Parameters": {
                "Payload": {
                  "identity": {
                    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
                    "ssn": "123-45-6789"
                  },
                  "firstName": "Jane",
                  "lastName": "Doe"
                },
                "FunctionName": "{Lambda ARN}"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "Verify address",
          "States": {
            "Verify address": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
              "Parameters": {
                "Payload": {
                  "street": "123 Main St",
                  "city": "Columbus",
                  "state": "OH",
                  "zip": "43219"
                },
                "FunctionName": "{Lambda ARN}"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Step5"
    },
    "Step5": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        something...
      },
      "End": true
      }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an explicit transition in your example to call `Step4` but assuming the order you have defined (`step1` -> `step2` -> `step3.1` -> `step3.3` -> `step4`)

This means the output from `step3.3` should be something like

```json
{
  "cat": "meow",
  "dog": "woof",
  "identity": { // this is whats missing
     "email": "jdoe@example.com",
     "ssn": "123-45-6789"
  }
}
```

this is what will get passed to each branch of your parallel state (`Step4`)

However, since you have an`InputPath` defined for `Step4."Verify identity"`, the effective input to the task becomes

```json
{
  "email": "jdoe@example.com",
  "ssn": "123-45-6789"
}
```

The error youre seeing

> An error occurred while executing the state 'Verify identity' (entered at the event id #19). Invalid path '$.identity' : Property ['identity'] not found in path $

means the **"identity"** key (aka `$.identity`) isn't getting added to the *output* of **Step3.3** (aka `$`)

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your response. For context, I don't want to pass the output of Step 3.3 to Step 4. But you're right about the order of the steps. Also, Step 3.3 is a `Pass` state. I just want to be able to build a scenario in Step 4 where I can select a part of the input instead of the whole input am adding in the definition for Step 4.

Comment: Ok so sounds like you're pretty much on the right track and based on that, whatever task is calling "Step4" has a malformed output (i.e. missing the "identity" field in the output object). Once you got that added you should be good to go :)

Comment: I am not able to figure out what's wrong there. Maybe the way I want it to work, it's not supposed to be at all. I just thought maybe there was a way to select a part of the input when you have a whole lot of input passed inside `Parameters` in the state machine definition.